# Why am I getting this error? (KeyError: 'username')

Tags: python, json

I'm asking the user for an email, and then sending it to an email verification api, which I then get certain bits of info from. I'm getting a KeyError: 'username' and I have no idea why I'm getting that error. It's also annoying to test since they ratelimit after ~5 attempts

```
import json, requests, sys

emailInput = ""

def printHelp():
    print("Proper usage is: python test.py [email]")

if len(sys.argv) < 2:
    printHelp()
    sys.exit()
elif len(sys.argv) == 2 and sys.argv[1] == "--help":
    printHelp()
    sys.exit()
elif len(sys.argv) == 2 and sys.argv[1] != "--help":
    emailInput = str(sys.argv[1])



url = 'https://api.trumail.io/v2/lookups/json?email=' + str(emailInput)
res = requests.get(url)
res.raise_for_status()

resultText = res.text
emailInfo = json.loads(resultText)


print("\nEmail Analyzer 1.0\n\nInformation for email: " + sys.argv[1])
print("=====================================================")
print("Username:         " + str(emailInfo["username"]))
print("Domain:           " + str(emailInfo["domain"]))
print("Valid Format:     " + str(emailInfo["validFormat"]))
print("Deliverable:      " + str(emailInfo["deliverable"]))
print("Full Inbox:       " + str(emailInfo["fullInbox"]))
print("Host Exists:      " + str(emailInfo["hostExists"]))
print("Catch All:        " + str(emailInfo["catchAll"]))
print("Disposable:       " + str(emailInfo["disposable"]))
print("Free:             " + str(emailInfo["free"]))
```

Comment: You could check for rate limit before trying to access `emailInfo`. Technically, there is `emailInfo.get('username', '')` which will return a default value `''` in case `username` does not exist in the dict.

Comment: If you want to avoid the rate limit for now, print or save the result somewhere durable (a local text file, a local pickle, etc) and then work on getting the code that handles the result working using that copy, before hooking it back up to the API.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is because a user enters an email that might seem valid - i.e. it's a valid email address with an `@` symbol etc. - but the email likely does not exist or is not in use.

For example, I ran your script with the following dummy input:

```
emailInput = 'acdefg@gmail.com'
```

After I added a `print(emailInfo)` statement for debugging purposes, this is what I found to be the output from the server:

```
{'Message': 'No response received from mail server'}
```

Therefore, your goal here will be to validate the server output. That is, in the case of a valid email that does not exist, you will receive an HTTP 200 (OK) response from the server with a `Message` field alone populated in the JSON response object. The task here will be to correctly detect the presence of this key, and then run a separate logic other than the happy path, which was already being handled above.

Answer (score 0):

Your error is coming from the fact that `emailInfo` does not have a key `username`. Perhaps use `emailInfo.get("username", default_value)`, where default_value is any value you would like if there is no username.

The line with the error is `print("Username:         " + str(emailInfo["username"]))`